# Word changing background when printing

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a document design made up in word (2010), but when I go to print it, it goes from this 
[image: Original document]
Document with background image and borders

to this 
[image: Printed document]
PDF printing with the top and bottom border broken into lines, through the document (or border gone and lines added).

I have already tried setting the background image as the water mark, and that did not work. I also added the image to the document and re-sized it, but that hid my header/footer (even though it was set to behind text).

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless this is some very common problem (in which case you would have found at least something to cite from your Google search), this type of problem is very difficult to figure out without knowing all of the settings and document characteristics.

Comment: @fixer1234 The page uses custom sizing from the default word layout (W:21 cm H:27.3cm).

Comment: A custom page size shouldn't do this.  I suspect it's something else.  It will take detective work, examining every variable.  All you've shared about the document is that the problem is happening with Word 2010 when you output to a PDF and then view the result in Acrobat Pro DC, and you're using a custom page size.  Without the actual document and software, people can only guess at the source of the problem.  We don't even know whether the issue is with the document, itself, or with the software.

Comment: @fixer1234 I made another background (same size) to use as a test, and as seen in the results (here http://i.imgur.com/Nagbxnv.png) the background is zooming out at print. The background image was made the exact same size as the page size.

Comment: After heaps of testing with several different images, I still always get the same end result. The background keeps shrinking and duplicating at print. Does anyone know how to fix this?